# Community Bumping Bot

Tags: support, questions

It seems like the `<>Community` bot bumps old unanswered questions but lately ( today ) it seems like all the questions that have been bumped have legitimate answers but OP just hasn't come back and checkmarked them. Is there a way to keep this from happening, like force marking as answered or something?

Examples of Community Bumped Topics today that clearly have an answer.

1. [Create a custom taxonomy template that loops through child categories in term order?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/107024/create-a-custom-taxonomy-template-that-loops-through-child-categories-in-term-or)
2. [Images not showing after moving site (but path id OK)](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/99493/images-not-showing-after-moving-site-but-path-id-ok)
3. [How to add menu support to a theme?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/135589/how-to-add-menu-support-to-a-theme)
4. [Getting Details Of Uploaded Image](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/54409/getting-details-of-uploaded-image)
5. [Is_search not working on search results page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/105021/is-search-not-working-on-search-results-page)

These are just the ones currently on the frontpage, there were more earlier that have faded off.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The point is very simple when you compare that to the ["unanswered questions" queue](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/unanswered)

> Unanswered is everything that has no answer(s) [with upvotes]

Just go and upvote the answer(s) if you <strike>think</strike> know those are correct and the question will vanish from the "unanswered" queue and count as "answered".

Answer (score 3):

The criteria are:

> Note that the posts eligible for bumping have gone at least 30 days with no activity, have at least one answer scoring 0 and none scoring more than that, and no accepted answer (also, they can't be locked or closed).
>
> https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184511/163749

So the answer is — upvote good answers! :) Upvoted answer makes question "answered" in stack's terminology, even in lack of *accepted* answer.